# Mensagem "Undefined index" quando o Checkbox está vazio - php/html

Tags: php

Estou com um problema que, quando o checkbox está vazio, é exibida a mensagem

> Undefined index

Já vi algumas soluções na internet, até aqui no fórum mesmo, mas nada solucionou o problema.

*Segue o cód. abaixo:*

```
<!-- Cód. html -->
<input type="checkbox" name="cb">
```

---

```
//Cód. php
<?php 

$check_B = $_POST['cb'];

if(isset($check_B)){

    echo "Checkbox selecionado.";

} else { echo "Checkbox não selecionado.";
?>
```

Obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve verificar se $_POST['cb'] existe e não `$check_B`

```
<?php  

if(isset($_POST['cb'])){
    $check_B = $_POST['cb'];
    echo "Checkbox selecionado.";

} else {
    echo "Checkbox não selecionado.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigada Erlon! Funcionou certinho.